# fit_generator() outputs different result than fit()

Tags: numpy, keras, generator

I have a problem with fit_generator() output, it outputs different result than fit() method. I have a directory where patients data are stored. patients_x have all features and patients_y have corresponding dependent variables Im trying to predict. The problem is when Im trying to load every patient and yield batches of his data every iteration (next iteration next patient obviously), i get different result as if i would do the same thing but instead of loading 1 patient every iteration I would load all patients at once and concatenate them. To summarize : if I load all patients into memory and then yield batches --> it outputs right result, but if i load every iteration just 1 patient (because I dont have enough RAM to load all data) and yield batches from that patient --> it outputs bad result. Ive cheked if the generator outputs the same batches of data, it does. Please help me if you can.

This generator outputs right result. Im passing the whole dataset

```
def new_gen_shuffle(batch_size, X_train, y_train):
    while True:
        indices = np.arange(X_train.shape[0])
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        for patient_batch in range(X_train.shape[0]):
                inds = indices[patient_batch * batch_size:(patient_batch + 1) * batch_size]
                batch_x = X_train[inds]
                batch_y = y_train[inds]
                if batch_x.shape[0] > 0 and batch_y.shape[0] > 0:
                    yield batch_x, batch_y
```

but this one does not work properly. Im yielding batches for every patient (every iteration with next patient). But both of them output the same batches

```
def batch_generator(batch_size, patients_x, patinets_y):
    while True:
        for patient in range(len(patients_x)):  
            X_train = np.load(path + "/" + patients_x[patient])
            y_train = np.load(path + "/" + patients_y[patient])
            indices = np.arange(X_train.shape[0])
            np.random.shuffle(indices)
            for patient_batch in range(X_train.shape[0]):
                inds = indices[patient_batch * batch_size:(patient_batch + 1) * batch_size]
                batch_x = X_train[inds]
                batch_y = y_train[inds]
                if batch_x.shape[0] > 0 and batch_y.shape[0] > 0:
                    yield batch_x, batch_y
```

Comment: When you shuffle the `indices` array, aren't you shuffling actual train cases in the first code, while in the second `X_train` isn't a batch, but rather a single train case and thus you're using a shuffled train case instead of a shuffled *order* of train cases?

Comment: In both cases i shuffle only the order of X_train and y_train indices so that later I dont yield batches straight from top to bottom but in more shuffled fashion. That is the common thing to do.

Comment: But isn't `X_train` different in each case? Does it have the same shape in both cases?

Comment: The thing is that in first case my X_train is whole dataset of concatenated smaller datasets, and in second case im looping through every one of those small datasets, so no they dont have the same shape, but the sum of shapes of all X_trains in second case is equal to the shape of X_train in first case.

Comment: Ok, but you use the same `X_train.shape[0]` and identical code for shuffling in both cases. Aren't you then shuffling the *whole* dataset in the first case, but only the contents of one specific smaller dataset in the second case?

Comment: Yep i shuffle only the indices of one small dataset per iteration, beacause i cant load all those datasets and concatenate them at once and then shuffle whole dataset. Thats why i load one small dataset per iteration, shuffle it and yield batches from it. In both cases generators output whole dataset as I wanted but the problem is that when i use fit_generator with first case --> it outputs right results and when I do the same with 2nd generator, it gives me bad results.

Comment: Yeah, but then isn't then `patient_batch` in the first case the same as `X_train` in the second case? So in the first case your batches are different too. In the first case you: took the whole dataset, shuffled it, created batches from each patient in the dataset. In the second case: you took a patient, shuffled it and created batches from a subset of the patient. Or do I understand it wrong?

Comment: Yes, basicaly in the first case I shuffle the whole dataset and then just keep yielding batches until it starts yielding batches with shape (0, something), because i go from 0 to the whole length of that dataset, and i run out of data before i reach len(X_train). And in the second case i do exactly the same but for each subtset of that whole dataset every iteration (as Im not able to load the whole dataset to memro at once)

Comment: I will stop, because we're just repeating. We established that the pools from which you're yielding batches aren't the same, right?! Let's say your database is like X(patients(a)). In first case you're creating batches consisting of patients, but in the second consisting of a.

Comment: yes, exactly so

Comment: But how are you then surprised you're getting a different result..?

Comment: It looks like this: Folder : `Patient1.npy`, `Patient2.npy`... `Patient100.npy`. In first case my X_train is all these npys concatenated, and batches are yielded from here. In the second case every iteration i load `PatientN.npy` which is X_train at this iteration,  yield batches from it and go to the second iteration and repeat steps untill i go through all Patients. Thats how i go through all data samples. But in first case i have to load this all to the memory, and in the second case I load only 1 patient per iteration so i dont run out of RAM. Hope now we understand each other.

Comment: I understand that. I guess you're doing some kind of machine learning. For example, let's say you want to predict if a patient has a disease. You have data with laboratory results for every patient and a label whether he has the disease or not. To train, you'll take patients and labels and try to make your model predict correctly. That's what you're doing in the first case. In the second case, you're taking a few random numbers from laboratory results of a single patient and try  to train a model to predict disease from that.

Comment: Not sure if its true, but could you please adjust the code so it fits my describtion in the comment above? I need to go through all patients and their data without loading it all to memory

Comment: Why not just load a few patients from random indices and concatenate them? This would be your batch.

Comment: Random indices are indices of datapoints of each `Patient.npy` from 0 to `len(np.load(Patient.npy))`